# setting a breakpoint when variable reaches specific value

Tags: gdb

Is there anyway to set a breakpoint when a variable reaches a specific value in GDB? For example, a variable take these values: 1 4 8 10 3 2  9 13 11 and I want to set a breakpoint when this variable reaches 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, set [breakpoint with condition](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html).

```
break ... if value==9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [watchpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) for this.

```
watch n > 9
```

...should break when the Boolean expression `n > 9` changes; that is, whenever n goes from smaller than or equal to 9 to bigger than 9 or vice-versa.